# Passing NID argument from views to panelizer

Tags: 7, views, panels

I am working on a complex site using Views and Panelizer.

I am trying to use Panelizer to display Views generated data, filtered by NID, for each advertisement.

To do that, I created a view called **Advertisements** with a **content pane** called *Display* which takes an NID as a *contextual filter*.

The NID filter is set to *Provide default value* -> *Content ID from URL*.

[image]

With that I am able to preview the field data of an existing article node when I provide it's NID as an argument.

However I have problems beyond this point :-(

I find my View content-pane in the **Views panes** section of the content area of Article's panelizer area - but there is no preview. 
This immediately suggest there is something wrong with the output.

[image]

This is confirmed when I save the configuration and visit an Advertisement node - my output does not display.

After some research, I return to Views and go into the *pane settings* -> *argument input* section. I set it to **From context** -> **Content ID**.

[image]

With the View saved, I return to my advertisement node to find the page still blank.

I am very stomped and a lot of time has been wasted on this.

Can anyone please advice what I'm doing wrong or missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same setup and issue. I could see the title of the view pane but no content even after I had made sure to set Argument input:Edit (in content pane view) to be:

- Argument source: From context
- Required context: Content ID

The reason I was not seeing content and only the title of view was simply because I'd forgotten I'd made a tpl of that view and had not yet cleared cache...

Comment: Why did they call it "Content ID"... everywhere else it's 'nid' or 'node id' ;_;